# Can you create a Google My Business listing for a farmers market which has a temporary address at a school?

Tags: seo, local-seo, google-my-business, address

I've been trying to find some ideas for this, but my Google searches have been rather fruitless. Even in with "farmers market" in quotes, it keeps on returning general SEO.

Can anyone point me in the right direction or share some ideas for how to perform local SEO for a farmers market.

The biggest issue I can see, is that the location is a school and from Google's perspective the school already operates at the business address.

I am assuming it would not be possible to create GMB listing with this address, so would it be at all possible to get in on the map?

I'm guessing that citations across market listings websites, and other other local listings would be pointless without a valid GMB listing.

Is there a way to create a GMB listing, or any other way to get it on the map or any other workarounds for local SEO?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GMB makes it pretty clear, that you must use a valid address... since real businesses have registered addresses. You need to register the address with local authorities if it does not have a registered physical address.

If you are location does not have anywhere for the post to be delivered too, i.e a field then you simply pay for a redirecting and forwarding service to another address. Forwarding your mail will obviously enable you to receive the GMB postcode that is needed to enable the listing.

Another method that is a workaround but not approved by Google is to use the same address as the school i.e `Unit 2` and change the marker, but you would need to inform the school to expect your postcard.

Summary, register the address if its a serious business, if not, don't list it on GMB.

Comment: I use Unit G for garage. ;-) I delete my original comment because I was not sure if recommending using a Unit ?? would always be a good idea. I did it. But I have an apartment building and added 3 units just a few years ago. What's one more? Cheers!!

Comment: Thank you @SimonHayter
That has definitely given me some ideas.